# Why wait DIFS in order to sense if the channel is idle

Tags: networking, wifi, protocols

Station waits in order to sense if the channel is idle DIFS and then starts transmission. My question is why wait DIFS and not SIFS only.
What problems, issues it may cause (sense for SIFS instead of DIFS)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** `SIFS` is not long enough to detect if the channel is indeed idle. The implication of waiting just `SIFS` instead of `DIFS` is that the MAC protocol shall no longer be able to detect busy channel, thus collisions may happen all the time, and thus poor channel efficiency.

**Long answer:**

- What is `SIFS`? The [standard](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.11-2012.html) defines that SIFS (Short Inter-Frame Space) is used to separate a `DATA` and `ACK` frames. A station (STA) receiving `DATA` will wait for `SIFS` before sending `ACK`. It should be as short as possible, basically just enough to decode the frame, MAC processing, and preparation time to send `ACK`. For 802.11n/ac, `SIFS` = 16 microseconds.
- What is `DIFS`? `DIFS` = `SIFS + 2*slot_time`. Similar to `SIFS`, `slot_time` is PHY-dependent. For 802.11n/ac, `slot_time` = 9 microseconds. `slot_time` is defined to be long enough to account for, among others, propogation delays, thus enable neighbouring STAs to detect transmitting STA's preamble.

Having said that, if a STA just waits for `SIFS` before transmitting, there is no way it can detect possible `ACK` frame being sent by a neighbouring STA at the exact same time - that leads to collisions and poor channel efficiency.

**Others:**

- If one `slot_time` is long enough to detect transmitting STA's preamble, why just not wait for `SIFS + slot_time` ? Well can be, but it is actually `PIFS` that is normally used by the AP only (to have higher access priority than normal STAs).
- Why wait *at least* `DIFS` before sending ? Given that `DIFS` is enough to determine whether the channel is busy or not, why not just wait for `DIFS` ? That's because there can be *multiple* STAs that are possibly sending the channel at the same time. If every STA just waits for `DIFS` then send immediately - well then that's another collision. That's why the standard mandates that if a STA sending the channel idle for `DIFS`, it can transmit immediately. *But* if a STA sending channel busy, it must wait for `DIFS` **plus a random backoff time** to avoid collisions. What is random backoff time ?? Time to google on 802.11 CSMD/CA then..
- For reference, there is [a similar Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030606/why-wait-sifs-time-before-sending-ack) that deals with `SIFS` and touched a bit on other channel access timing.

Answer (score 0):

The time used in sensing the channel by a station and then sends RTS, to the other station.This overall time is called DIFS(DCF, Interframe Space). The station first time sense the see the station is not used by the other stations and then sends RTS(Request To Send).
If the chanel is idle then, channel wakes up from power saving mode to accept the RTS from a station so some time also spent in this process.

Comment: thanks, but from the answer it is still unclear why wait DIFS, when the station may wait less - SIFS and then start transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose three stations are sensing a busy medium. If the medium becomes idle at *t* , then all three stations will not be   able to realise that medium is idle at time *t*. They will realise it only after time (*t* + DIFS).

So it means when medium becomes idle , all stations will realise it after DIFS duration. It is a kind of *lag*. It is not a waiting period.